# Julia Libexpat xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, julia

In the following XML snippet, I would like to get all Ids that have an "S2" in the summary text.

```
<Objects>
    <Tasks>
        <Task Id="A10">
            <Title>T1</Title>
            <Summary>S1</Summary>
        </Task>
        <Task Id="A11">
            <Title>T2</Title>
            <Summary>S2</Summary>
        </Task>
    </Tasks>
</Objects>
```

The following works on https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

```
/Objects/Tasks/Task[ Summary[ contains(text(),S2) ]]/@Id
```

but fails with Julia code

```
using LibExpat
et=LibExpat.xp_parse(instring);
tasks=et[xpath"/Objects/Tasks/Task[Summary[contains(text(),S2)]]/@Id"]
```

> UndefVarError: search not defined

Is the above not implemented in [LibExpat.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/LibExpat.jl) or is the `xpath` syntax different?

Comment: Does `(et)[xpath"your/search/string"]` or `xpath(et, "your/search/string")` work for you?

Comment: this works: et[xpath"/Objects/Tasks/Task"]

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are using the wrong xpath and its returning 2 elements.

Here's the correct xpath. (changed S2 to 'S2')

```
//Objects/Tasks/Task[Summary[contains(text(),'S2')]]/@Id
```

Comment: I still see "UndefVarError: search not defined"